# Excel VBA - copying data depending on column name

Tags: excel, runtime-error, copy-paste, vba

I have a problem: using three separate worksheets (Source 1, Source 2, Template) I have to take data from the source files and paste it onto the Template, depending on the column names.
I.e. Source 1's first three columns' names match those on the Template, and the Template's fourth row matches the fourth row matches Source 2's fourth.

Here's what I got this far (it is incomplete). 
Checking other threads I made a "derivation" of an example, but I still can not make it work. I get runtime error 9 on the line marked with a comment within Copy_Columns()

```
Sub MasterCopy()

    Open_Files
    Copy_Columns

End Sub

Sub Open_Files()
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:Source 1.xls"
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:Source 2.xls"
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:Template.xls"
End Sub

Sub Copy_Columns()

    Dim Source1 As Worksheet
    Source1 = Application.Workbooks("C:Source 1.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1") 'here is where the error appears
    Source1.Select

    Dim columnToBeCopied As Integer
    columnToBeCopied = getColumnName("Source1", "columnToBeCopied")

    Dim template As Worksheet
    template = Application.Workbooks("C:Template.xls").Worksheets("Data")
    template.Activate

    Dim columnToBePasted As Integer
    columnToBePasted = getColumnName("template", "columnToBePasted")

    Sheets("Source1").Columns(columnToBeCopied).Copy Sheets("template").Columns(columnToBePasted)

End Sub

Public Function getColumnName(ByVal sheetName As String, ByVal columnName As String)

    Dim lastColumn As Integer
    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Column

    Dim iterator As Integer
    iterator = 0
    While (iterator <= lastColumn)
        If (LCase(Sheets(sheetName).Range(1, iterator)) = LCase(columnName)) Then
            getColumnName = iterator
        Else: iterator = iterator + 1
        End If
    Wend
    If IsEmpty(getColumnName) Then getColumnName = 0

End Function
```

There's somewhat close examples but they are either too complex (this is my first time using VBA) or too "obscure" in terms that they use a, o, x, b as variable names...
Any help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the line with the error to this:

`Set Source1 = Workbooks("Source 1").Sheets("Sheet1")`